# Canvas: fillText() on android 2.x browser

Tags: android, html, canvas

```
context.fillText(text,x,y,maxWidth);
```

maxWidth parameter won't work on android 2.x it is completely ignored

Comment: Are you assigning the canvas boundary via a variable called maxWidth and in the console what is that variable returning?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the next function?

```
fillText(text, x, y [,maxWidth])
```

Source: [safari html canvas guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/AddingText/AddingText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010542-CH6-SW4)